# Shapeless - Deduplicating types in Coproduct

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

Given that I have a type of `Int :+: Int :+: String :+: CNil`, is there an easy way to turn it into `Int :+: String :+: CNil`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "easy". I'm pretty sure there's no straightforward way to perform this operation by composing coproduct operations that are available off-the-shelf in Shapeless, but writing your own type class to do this is reasonably straightforward (at least as far as these things go).

I'm going to assume a couple of things that aren't specified in your requirements:

1. You want the types in the resulting coproduct to be unique (e.g. you're not just collapsing adjacent elements as in your example).
2. In the case of non-adjacent duplicated types, you want the *last* duplicate to be included in the result.

It wouldn't be too hard to adjust the solution below if these assumptions aren't accurate—the core idea would be the same.

A complete solution looks like this:

```
import shapeless.{ :+:, CNil, Coproduct, DepFn1, Inl, Inr }
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject

trait Unique[C <: Coproduct] extends DepFn1[C] {
  type Out <: Coproduct
}

object Unique extends LowPriorityUnique {
  type Aux[C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: Coproduct] = Unique[C] { type Out = Out0 }

  def apply[C <: Coproduct](implicit unC: Unique[C]): Aux[C, unC.Out] = unC

  implicit val uniqueCNil: Aux[CNil, CNil] = new Unique[CNil] {
    type Out = CNil
    def apply(c: CNil): CNil = c
  }

  implicit def uniqueCCons1[L, R <: Coproduct](implicit
    inj: Inject[R, L],
    unR: Unique[R]
  ): Aux[L :+: R, unR.Out] = new Unique[L :+: R] {
    type Out = unR.Out

    def apply(c: L :+: R): unR.Out = unR(
      c match {
        case Inl(l) => inj(l)
        case Inr(r) => r
      }
    )
  }
}

class LowPriorityUnique {
  implicit def uniqueCCons0[L, R <: Coproduct](implicit
    unR: Unique[R]
  ): Unique[L :+: R] { type Out = L :+: unR.Out } = new Unique[L :+: R] {
    type Out = L :+: unR.Out

    def apply(c: L :+: R): L :+: unR.Out = c match {
      case Inl(l) => Inl(l)
      case Inr(r) => Inr(unR(r))
    }
  }
}
```

We can walk through this code step-by-step.

```
trait Unique[C <: Coproduct] extends DepFn1[C] {
  type Out <: Coproduct
}
```

This is our type class. It characterizes a coproduct `C`, and for any instance it has an output type that's unique determined by `C` that is also a coproduct. From `DepFn1` we get a method `apply` that takes a `C` and returns an `Out`; this is what we'll be implementing in our instances below.

In the companion object we have a couple of lines that are basically boilerplate—they're not strictly necessary, but they support convenient, idiomatic use of this type class:

```
type Aux[C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: Coproduct] = Unique[C] { type Out = Out0 }

def apply[C <: Coproduct](implicit unC: Unique[C]): Aux[C, unC.Out] = unC
```

The first line lets us avoid writing type refinements (`Foo[X] { type Bar = Bar0 }`) everywhere, and the second lets us write `Unique[C]` instead of `implicitly[Unique[C]]` (and also returns a refined result instead of the useless unrefined `Unique[C]`).

Next we have our base case:

```
implicit val uniqueCNil: Aux[CNil, CNil] = new Unique[CNil] {
  type Out = CNil
  def apply(c: CNil): CNil = c
}
```

This is fairly straightforward: if we get an empty coproduct, we know its elements are already unique.

Next we have a couple of inductive cases. The first, `uniqueCCons1`, covers the case where the head of the coproduct exists in the tail, and the second, `uniqueCCons0`, covers the case where it doesn't. Because `uniqueCCons1` applies to a subset of the cases `uniqueCCons0` covers, we have to prioritize the two instances explicitly. I'm using a subclass to give `uniqueCCons0` lower priority, since I think this is the simplest approach.

The implementations of these two instances may look a little messy, but the logic isn't actually that complicated. In both cases we have an inductive `Unique[R]` instance; the difference is that in the `1` case we first inject the head into the tail (relying on Shapeless's `Inject` type class to witness that `L` occurs in `R`) and then apply `unR`, where in the `0` case we apply it only to the tail and leave the head unchanged.

It works like this:

```
scala> type C = Int :+: String :+: CNil
defined type alias C

scala> Unique[C]
res0: Unique[Int :+: String :+: shapeless.CNil]{type Out = Int :+: String :+: shapeless.CNil} = LowPriorityUnique$$anon$3@2ef6f000

scala> Unique[C].apply(Inl(1))
res1: Int :+: String :+: shapeless.CNil = Inl(1)

scala> type C2 = Int :+: String :+: Int :+: CNil
defined type alias C2

scala> Unique[C2].apply(Inr(Inr(Inl(1))))
res2: String :+: Int :+: shapeless.CNil = Inr(Inl(1))

scala> Unique[C2].apply(Inl(1))
res3: String :+: Int :+: shapeless.CNil = Inr(Inl(1))
```

Which matches our requirements above.

Comment: Ah so `Inject` is the typeclass I need. Thanks Travis! Will be great if you can add some notes regarding the fact that an `Inject` proves that our head type `L` is found in `R`! (If my understanding is correct)

Comment: @JacobWang Good idea—I just added a note.

Answer (score 5):

Is this an easy way?

```
  import shapeless.{:+:, =:!=, CNil, Coproduct, Inl, Inr, unexpected}

  trait Deduplicate[C <: Coproduct] {
    type Out <: Coproduct
    def apply(c: C): Out
  }
  object Deduplicate {
    type Aux[C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: Coproduct] = Deduplicate[C] { type Out = Out0 }
    def instance[C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: Coproduct](f: C => Out0): Aux[C, Out0] = new Deduplicate[C] {
      override type Out = Out0
      override def apply(c: C): Out = f(c)
    }

    implicit def zero: Aux[CNil, CNil] = instance(_ => unexpected)
    implicit def one[H]: Aux[H :+: CNil, H :+: CNil] = instance(identity)
    implicit def duplicates[H, T <: Coproduct](implicit
      dedup: Deduplicate[H :+: T]): Aux[H :+: H :+: T, dedup.Out] = instance {
      case Inl(h) => dedup(Inl(h))
      case Inr(c) => dedup(c)
    }
    implicit def noDuplicates[H, H1, T <: Coproduct](implicit
      dedup: Deduplicate[H1 :+: T],
      ev1: H =:!= H1): Aux[H :+: H1 :+: T, H :+: dedup.Out] = instance {
      case Inl(h) => Inl(h)
      case Inr(c) => Inr(dedup(c))
    }
  }
  implicit class DeduplicateOps[C <: Coproduct](c: C) {
    def deduplicate(implicit dedup: Deduplicate[C]): dedup.Out = dedup(c)
  }

  implicitly[Deduplicate.Aux[String :+: Int :+: Int :+: String :+: String :+: CNil,
    String :+: Int :+: String :+: CNil]]
```

Comment: You beat me by a few minutes, but I don't think code-only answers are a good idea for complex problems like this, so I'm going to leave mine.